# Validation of wholesale customer

Tags: magento-1.7, cms, login

I have made **different group** for **customers** and added **different prices** as **per customer**  group for products.From CMS I changed a customer group and added him in wholesale I have different login links for wholesale and general group user now my question how can I validate customer where he is from wholesale or general group?

Price is showing as per group if I login from wholesale or from general but customer from general group also login form wholesale group login

Login URL general customer

`www.domain.com/customer/account/login/`

Login URL for wholesale

`www.domain.com/wholesale`

How can I manage this form CMS or by using any extension or module? 
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can check customer group by customer email id before login

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email); //load customer by email id
$customerGroupId =  $customer->getGroupId();
```

and then check if customer's group id is wholesale then allow to login

```
if($customerGroupId == 'wholesale_group_id')
{
  //code for login
}
else
{
  //code for error messsage
}
```

Comment: which file i need to edit to put this code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this event to observe customer login predispatch

```
controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginpost



<events>
  <controller_action_predispatch_mycustomroute_mycustom_myaction>
     <observers>
    <trigger_before_login>
     <class>YourModuleModeltype/observer</class>
    <method>CustomerAccountLoginPost</method>
    </trigger_before_login>
    </observers>
  </controller_action_predispatch_mycustomroute_mycustom_myaction>     
</events>
```

in Observer.php

```
public function CustomerAccountLoginPost($observer) {
    $params = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams(); //get post value
   // here is logic 
}
```